# Generalization between 2 datasets of same domain

Tags: neural-network

Suppose that I'm have 2 different datasets of same domain and trained a model with d1 dataset. Can we generalize the model to predict d2 dataset ? Is it possible or not. For example consider Dataset D1, Dataset D2 with images of cats and dogs and model is trained on D1. Then can we use the model to predict D2.

Any Kind of reference is helpful

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is basically the point of training a model in the first place. Why would you train a model on D1, where you already know the answer, if you could *not* apply it anywhere else?

Comment: I would like to know about the distributions what if the D1 and D2 distributions are different? Will the generalization concept of Deep learning still holds?

Comment: You can look for transfer learning. It can work (with reasonable limitations) even when the datasets have different distributions

Comment: @Nikos M Even if we use transfer learning we are supposed to train/fine tune model with dataset(D2). My question is even D1 and D2 images are same but distribution may or may not be same So can i use model for D2 prediction

Comment: Under some assumptions it is possible yes. Unfortunately I cannot state the asumptions needed. Trial and error can be a guide

Comment: Im not aware of those assumptions any kind of reference might be helpful @ Nikos M

Comment: First of all, it is reasonable that there are some conditions met where indeed the generalisation is possible (this stems from the nature of learning and the models used). However the conditons can be very specific and complex, so I cannot state more than that. That is why trial and error might be speedier than trying to figure them out

Comment: Ok Thank You @Nikos M